# Referrer not showing up from site A to site B with a 301 redirect

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, referrer

I'm having some troubles understanding the way redirects work. I tried setting up a 301 redirect from site A to site B but when a user arrives to site B it doesn't show site A as a referrer. Is there any way to make it work properly?

Comment: Where is your php code?

Comment: This question is going to be very hard to get a good answer for unless you post the code from your attempt at creating a redirect.